# How to get every item of every folder in SharePoint Library in C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In my project, i have to show all the name of items of the Library path that user give me. If no folder the library contains => no problem.

However, there are many folders, sub-folders, sub-sub-folders, sub^n-folders. I cannot loop all the folders, which get a endless loop. I don't need the code that i just need the concept of how to loop all folders.

Therefore, i need help from all of you experienced programmer.

The result should be:

```
item name   folder name
---------------------------------------------
item1
item2
item1        subF1
item1        subF2
item1        subF2sub1
.
.
```

My idea:

```
// path of library and folder is URL. For example, http://example.com/libraryName/subF2/subF2sub1/item1
//if i get all folders'path, i can then get the file name by those paths.
// i won't paste my code here because there are >100 lines.

void checkFolderExist(libraryPathByUser)
{
  if("folderInLibrary" != nil)
   {
      foreach (var folder in library)
      {
         string folderPath = getFolderPath(folder);
         strList.Add(folderPath);
         // so, how about sub-folder in the folder?
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `SPQuery` object and set its `Scope` attribute to `RecursiveAll`, for example:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
SPFolder folder = get the folder object by folder path
query.Folder = folder;
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query>your query goes here</Query></View>";
SPListItemCollection items = yourLibrary.GetItems(query);
Dictionary<string, List<SPListItem>> folderItems = new Dictionary<string, SPListItem[]>();

foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    // If items are files
    SPFile file = item.Web.GetFile(item.Url);
    string folderName = file.ParentFolder.Name;

    if (!folderItems.ContainsKey(folderName))
    {
        folderItems[folderName] = new List<SPListItem>();
    }

    folderItems[folderName].Add(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, i also need the folder name as the result    mentioned above. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @kingyau If your list items are all files, then you can try `SPFile file = item.Web.GetFile(item.Url); string folderName = file.ParentFolder.Name;`

Comment: So, what i need to do which is finding the first level of the library to check the folder exist, then execute your suggestion in a `foreach(var folderPath in firstLevelFolders)`?

Comment: @kingyau I've updated the code, you can create a dictionary to group items by folder name. It doesn't loop folders.

Comment: sorry, i am confused at line 2. What variable should i give it?  The library's path? Or the path of the first folder level of that library?

Comment: @kingyau It's the path of the first folder, you can get the folder by `yourLibrary.ParentWeb.GetFolder(first folder level of the library)`.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will recursively search all the artifacts and store in listItem object. It is using csom though.

```
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://Servername/");
    List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml =
        @"<View Scope='Recursive' />";

    ClientOM.ListItemCollection listItems =
        sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var item in listItems)
    {
    }
```

Not sure if you are looking for Clientside code or not.